# javascript switch statement and Ajax status

Tags: javascript

Firebug is giving me a syntax error on line 10 below:

`switch(xmlhttp.readyState) {`

This is directly from chap 2 of the Book 'Ajax Patterns and Best Practices' by Christian Gross. Thanks in advance. I can't seem to see the syntax error. Any help appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Page</title>

<script language="JavaScript" src="/lib/factory.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp = FactoryXMLHttpRequest();
function AsyncUpdateEvent() {
switch(xmlhttp.readyState) {
case 0:
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "uninitialized";
break;
case 1:
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "loading";
break;
case 2:
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "loaded";
break;
case 3:
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "interactive";
break;
case 4:
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "complete";
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
break;
}
}
function GetIt(url) {
if(xmlhttp) {
xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = AsyncUpdateEvent;
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="GetIt('/chap02/serverhang.aspx')">Get a document</button>
<p><table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Document</td>
<td>
<span id="status">No Result</span>
</td>
<td>
<span id="result">No Result</span>
</td></tr>
</table></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't get a syntax error when I type the function into the Firebug console.

Comment: it would be useful to see the `FactoryXMLHttpRequest()` function.

Comment: ... also it would be useful to see exactly what this error looks like.

Comment: Yep this sounds like an error in `/lib/factory.js`...

Comment: Ok - I was under the mistaken impression that factory.js was an existing utility.. I have now created it but still getting the same error probably because I have not placed it in the correct location. On my Windows machine C:/ drive I placed the lib dir with factory.js in the same directory as the script and it didn't seem to work. Running under Firebug I have no clue where to put it.. Thanks again in advance.